# Hiss on Spotify

Tags: spotify

Quite often I hear quite noticeable white noise in the background on Spotify.

Any suggestion what this is?

Just checking now - I went back to a song that had it, and it doesn't appear to be there anymore. So I don't think it's to do with the individual tracks.

This is when listening to tracks that I have saved for offline play.

Comment: On a more serious note, its all digital, so the first chance for "noise" to be introduced is at the hardware level. How can you reproduce it? Try moving your mobile phone about, that generates a huge amount of EM radiation.

Comment: Only Spotify? Does this happen playing anything else? This would be hardware level tbh.